# How to repeat embedded type in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this class that I'm trying to map in Hibernate 3.6.x

```
@Entity @Table(name = "address") @Inheritance()
public abstract class Address {
    @Column(name = "address_type") @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private final AddressType addressType;

    @Embedded @AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine", column = @Column(name = "address_line1"))})
    private final AddressLine addressLine1;

    @Embedded @AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine", column = @Column(name = "address_line2"))})
    private final AddressLine addressLine2;

    @Embedded @AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine", column = @Column(name = "address_line3"))})
    private final AddressLine addressLine3;

    @Embedded @AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine", column = @Column(name = "address_line4"))})
    private final AddressLine addressLine4;

    @Embedded @AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine", column = @Column(name = "address_line5"))})
    private final AddressLine addressLine5;

    @Embedded @AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "postcode", column = @Column(name = "postcode"))})
    private final Postcode postcode;
}
```

I'm getting this error. (Which I don't fully understand - can someone explain it?)

> Repeated column in mapping for entity:
>   Address column: addressLine (should
>   be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Although the @Embeddable AddressLine is just a object wrapping a string, I would like to keep the type so I can add behaviour/rules later on.

Any suggests that would allow this type of configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm ashamed to say that the error I was getting from this question was due to a copy & paste crime.

Although not in the question code, but in my actual code base, the @Column annotation name value within the duplicated AddressLines 1,2,3, and 4 were not changed to be unique.

For example - This is *BAD* as both @Column name values are the same of "address_line1"

```
@Embedded @AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine", column = @Column(name = "address_line1"))})
private final AddressLine addressLine1;

@Embedded @AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine", column = @Column(name = "address_line1"))})
private final AddressLine addressLine2;
```

If all column names are unique this example will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used @AttributeOverride but I know this error message. It is caused by multiple mapping of the column with same name, which in this case means, that Hibernate have ignored your column override definition.

However, in my case, I was using @ManyToOne classes, so the solution was @JoinColumns definition overriding original column names.